# How to block non-vpn traffic on Sierra?

Tags: network, macos, vpn, firewall

I use an openvpn client to a private server.

However, when I run `pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf` I have the following error that i can't fix on line 20 referring to antispoofing. If I remove the antispoofing line, it works.

Any ideas?

My config is as follows:

```
# Options
set block-policy drop
set fingerprints "/etc/pf.os"
set ruleset-optimization basic
set skip on lo0

# Interfaces
vpn_intf = "{ utun0 utun1 utun2 utun3 }"

# Ports
allowed_vpn_ports = "{ 1:65535 }"

# Table with allowed IPs
table <allowed_vpn_ips> persist file "/etc/pf.anchors/vpn.list" file "/etc/pf.anchors/custom.list"

# Block all outgoing packets
block out all

# Antispoof protection
antispoof for $vpn_intf inet

# Allow outgoing packets to specified IPs only
pass out proto icmp from any to <allowed_vpn_ips>
pass out proto {tcp udp} from any to <allowed_vpn_ips> port $allowed_vpn_ports

# Allow traffic for VPN interfaces
pass out on $vpn_intf all
```

This is the error that i receive.

```
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
/etc/pf.anchors/org.vpnonly.pf.rules:20: rule expands to no valid combination
pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded
pfctl: load anchors
```

This is in Sierra 10.12.1.